# How is memory organized inside a stack frame?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Speaking of the order of parameters, return addresses, local variables and other block statements, how are they pushed inside the stack frame and how that particular order works? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this concept.

Comment: This actually differs quite a bit on different platforms. The CPU type, operating system and even programming language influences the "callling convention" as its called.

Comment: Google _stack frame layout C_